# Replacement for Touch.FrameReported in Windows Phone 8.1 / Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

In my old Windows Phone 8.0 project i use Touch.FrameReported for Multitouch detect. But I can't find it in Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile Universal App.
Is there a similar command in wp 8.1 and wp 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CoreWindow.Pointer***` events. You can distinguish the fingers (touch contacts) by comparing the `Pointer.PointerId` property.

```
private void PointerPressedHandler(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType != PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
        var pointerId = point.PointerId;
        // TODO
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```